# Meteor constructor name shortened to one letter in production

Tags: heroku, coffeescript, meteor, iron-router

This issue is a bit baffling. On Meteor, I'm using iron-router and minimongoid, among other things. All packages are up-to-date. I'm also using coffeescript.

I have an AppController extending iron-router's RouteController. I've defined a function that translates the constructor's name into a string I can use as an HTML class:

```
viewName: () =>
    name = this.constructor.name
    _(_.str.underscored(name)).strLeft("_controller")
```

In development, this works fine.

In production, this constructor name ends up as a single letter; I've seen it be r, n, or m. Minimongoid seems to be running into a similar issue, as those class names have also been reduced to one letter.

I'm using this buildpack: https://github.com/oortcloud/heroku-buildpack-meteorite.git

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Meteor uses uglify to minimize your JS code in order to minimize bandwidth. One step in this process is changing all the local variable names to a more concise form, starting with those one-letter names you see. Because of this you cannot rely on variable names in the way you do. A possible solution is to use a dictionary instead.

Comment: Ok, I figured it might be something like that -- thanks much.